# SAS Proc Export to .txt - export variable names even if file is null

Tags: sas

I have a set of code that I run regularly and sometime that code produces a table with all null values. Since I have this automated I want the column headers to still be exported to the txt file even when the value is null.

Thanks!
B

Example:

A  B  C
.  .  .

Current txt Output = blank;

Ideal:

A, B, C

Comment: Please post some code so we can see what you are currently doing...

Comment: I am currently using the following code and it does not export headers for the null table.

proc export data=testvalue
    outfile="C:\test.txt"
    label dbms=dlm replace; 
    delimiter='@';   
    putnames = yes;
  run;

Answer (score 1):

The following code outputs headers even when there are no values in the dataset.

```
proc export data=test outfile='C:\test.txt' dbms=dlm replace;
    delimiter=' ';
run;
```